# Open .npy or .txt files in Google Colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm new to python and I know there are lots of posts explaining how to upload files to Google Colab (step 1) but I could find nothing on how to actually use them in the code (step 2).
Could anyone explain me step by step how do I go from step 1 to having a fully functioning numpy array in my code?

thanks a lot!
[Tried to upload a print screen image that has the downloaded files tab on the left and the code on the right illustrating what i described above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DMLD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a leading `/` on your path. Try `/content/export.txt`

Comment: It didn't solve the problem... but thanks for your answer!

Comment: Problem solved! I had saved the file as a dictionary of arrays and that was causing an error. Once I saved as a ndarray it worked! thanks a lot for your tip, was an essential step solving the problem!